# What does "しっくりきます" mean?

Tags: translation

I would like to ask what does "しっくりきます" mean?

Answer (score 3):

その説明で 私は しっくり きました。That explanation made me assured. My doubt was evaporated.

この部品 と あの部品は しっくり はまります。This part and that part fits exactly. These parts fit to a T.

Answer (score 2):

It is an expression of feeling used when something fits snugly and there is no discomfort.

Please feel free to correct my English

Comment: @hanishi-san: Please feel free to revise or consolidate your answers into one.

Comment: I tried, but this may not be what you'd expected.

Answer (score 2):

この部品 と あの部品は しっくり はまります。->この部品 と あの部品はピッタリはまります。

Comment: ぴったり is more adequate then しっくり.

Comment: その説明で 私は しっくり きました。 is correct. We use it in that context.